# Exporting .p12 certificate through Xcode -> Preferences

Tags: ios, xcode

I did create my Developer certificate using some other mac few days back. Now I want to export that certificate to my new mac. Can I do it through Xcode -> Preferences and export from my new computer. When I did it through my new mac, it created a .P12 file but still I am getting "Code signing identity does not match error". Giving a clear view on how the certificates work will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: its available in keychain goto your keychain and then check the .p12 is available

Comment: It was available in older mac. Now on other mac can i get it through Xcode -> Preferences. As per my opinion, I don't think so because private key is stored locally on the mac.